# Where can the symbol \lessequivlnt be found?

Tags: bibtex, unicode, amssymb, zotero, better-bibtex

I'm using Zotero with Better BibTeX to manage a bibliography. The latter, I believe, translates the symbol ≲ into `\lessequivlnt`, which throws an Undefined Symbol error upon compilation.

I don't see this anywhere in the Comprehensive Symbols list, though I do see the similar `\lesssim` provided by `amssymb`.

I do see this symbol listed in [an xml file on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Math/characters/unicode.xml) (with its equivalent AMS `\lesssim`) and also in `unicode.sty`, though simply loading that package failed.

What might be the easiest way to load this symbol, and any others of similar class that my citation manager might emit? (I'd rather not maintain my own translation table to symbols in `amssymb`.)

Comment: just add `\let\lessequivlnt=\lesssim`  I'm not sure that name is really used anywhere

Comment: not really related but the current version of the unicode xml file is at https://github.com/w3c/xml-entities/blob/gh-pages/unicode.xml

Comment: If `lesssim` is better than `\lessequivlnt` I'll be happy to change that in BBT. I'd appreciate it if you could open an issue for this at https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/new/choose